# What is the proper way to cancel coroutines with common mutex

Tags: kotlin, mutex, coroutine

I have run into this problem.

I have (at least) 6 coroutines which works on a map which is managed through a mutex.

Sometimes I need to cancel one, more or all the coroutines in different scenarios.

What is the best way to cope with the mutex when cancelling the coroutine(s) ? (The fact is that I really don't know if the cancelling coroutine was the one which locked the mutex). Do the mutex "system" has any neat trick to cope with this ?

---

**ADDITION 2021.09.30 11:28 GMT+2 (DST)**

My coding is fairly complex, so I simplify it and show the main problem here

```
... 
class HomeFragment:Fragment(){
...
private lateinit var googleMap:GoogleMap

val mapMutex = Mutex()
...

override fun onViewCreated(view:View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
...
binding.fragmentHomeMapView?.geMapAsync { _googleMap ->

  _googleMap?.let{ safeGoogleMap ->
    googleMap = safeGoogleMap
  }?:let{
    Message.error("Error creating map (null)") 
  }

  ...
   
  homeViewModel.apply {
    ...
    //observer & coroutine 1 
    liveDataMapFlagged?.observe(
      viewLifeCycleOwner
    ){flaggedMapDetailResult->

      //Here I want to stop the lifecycleScope job below if it is already 
      //running and do some cleanup before entering (do I need to access the
      //mutex if cleanup influence the google map ?)
      //If I cancel the job, will the mutex then unlock gracefully ?

      flaggedMapDetailResult?.apply {
        ...
        lifecycleScope.launchWhenStarted { //Here I want to catch the job with i.e 'flagJob = lifeCycleScope.launchWhe...'  
          ...
          withContext(Dispatchers.Default){
            ...
            mapMutex.withLock {   //suspends if locked
              withContext(Dispatchers.Main){
                selectedSiteMarker?.remove()
                selectedCircle?.remove() 
                ... // Doing some cleanup... removing markers
              }
              ... // Creating new markers
              var flaggedSiteMarkerLatLng = coordinateSiteLatitude?.let safeLatitude@{safeLatitude->
                 return@safeLatitude coordinateSiteLongitude?.let safeLongitude@{safeLongitude->
                 return@safeLongitude LatLng(safeLatitude,safeLongitude)
                 }
              }
              ...
              flaggedSiteMarkerLatLng?.let { safeFlaggedSiteMarkerLatLng ->
                val selectedSiteOptions =     
                  MarkerOptions()
                    .position(safeFlaggedSiteMarkerLatLng)
                    .anchor(0.5f,0.5f)
                    .visible(flaggedMarkerState)
                    .flat(true)
                    .zIndex(10f)
                    .title(setTicketNumber(ticketNumber))
                    .snippet(appointmentName?:"Name is missing")
                    .icon(vSelectedSiteIcon)

              selectedSiteMarker = withContext(Dispatchers.Main){
                googleMap.addMarker(selectedSiteOptions)?.also{
                  it.tag = siteId
                }
              }
              ... //Do some more adding

            } //End mutex
            ...
          }//End dispatchers default
          ...
        }//End lifecycleScope.launchWhenStarted
        ...
      }?:let{//End apply
        ...//Cleanup if no data present
        lifeCycleScope.launchWhenStarted{ //Shoud harvest Job and stop above
                                          //if it is called before ending...
                                          //if necessary
          mapMutex.withLock{
            //Cleanup markers         
          }
        } 
      }
      ...
    }//End observer 1


    //observer 2
    liveDataMapListFromFiltered2?.observer(
      viewLifeCycleOwner
    ){mapDetailList ->

      //Should check if job below is running and cancel gracefully and
      //clean up data 

      ...//Do some work on mapDetailList and create new datasets
      lifecycleScope.launchWhenStarted{ //Scope start (should harvest job)
        ...
        withContext(Dispatchers.Default) //Default context
        {
           ...//Do some heavy work on list (no need for mutex)
           
        }

        mapMutex.withLock {
          withContext(Dispatchers.Main)
          {
            //Do work on googlemap. Move camera etc.
          } 

        }

        ...//Do other not map related work
        
        mapMutex.withLock {
          withContext(Dispatchers.Main)
          {
            //Do work on googlemap. Move camera etc.
          } 

        }

        ...//Do other not map related work

        mapMutex.withLock {
          withContext(Dispatchers.Main)
          {
            //Do work on googlemap. Move camera etc.
          } 
        }//end mutex
      }//end scope 
    }//end observer 2 
  }//end viewmode
}//end gogleMap
```

Comment: did you check that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67842732/how-to-proper-cancel-coroutineworker

Comment: What is your concern regarding cancelling and mutex? Are you concerned that after cancelling a coroutine which is currently holding a lock, it won't be properly released? Or that the cancel will happen in the middle of modifying some data, so it might leave an inconsistent state?

Comment: The concistence of data do I manage, but the fact that the mutex is locked or not by the coroutine I am cancelling is worse.

Comment: I have just added the code scemantics where the proble is showing 3 of the main coroutine scenaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, a `cancel` is a normal exception, which you can just catch in order to run clean-up operations, you can see the example on [closing  resources](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/cancellation-and-timeouts.html#closing-resources-with-finally).

In addition, since you can still by cancelled during clean-up, for critical operations you can [prevent further cancellation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/cancellation-and-timeouts.html#run-non-cancellable-block). Put together your job can have something like:

```
my_mutex.lock()
try {
    // locked stuff
} finally {
    withContext(NonCancellable) {
        // clean up
        my_mutex.unlock()
    }
}
```

I think `NonCancellable` is overdoing it in the case of only an unlock since it is supposed to be atomic, but I am not sure. If this is the case, I just looked up this pattern and apparently this is so common they have something  [more nifty](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/shared-mutable-state-and-concurrency.html#mutual-exclusion):

```
mutex.withLock {
    // locked stuff
}
```

As it says in the link

> There is also withLock extension function that conveniently represents `mutex.lock(); try { ... } finally { mutex.unlock() }` pattern.

Comment: Ahah.. I am using `mutex.withLock { ... }, I'll explain a little more in my post above.

Comment: @RoarGrønmo Then looks like you're good. That is the "best" or idomatic way to deal with your problem.

Comment: I wonder if the mutex releases the lock if I stop the coroutine job ?

Comment: Just added more info in the post above

Comment: @RoarGrønmo Like I wrote, the answer is yes, it does.

Comment: Even when using `job.cancel`? (I need with teaspoon sometimes)...

Comment: @RoarGrønmo hehe, I'll add sugar to the tea spoon. Yes, even with cancel. The whole point of the contect `withLock` is to do what I wrote at the start of the answer - catch the cancel exception (when you cancel it throws an exception in the job), unlock the mutex, and only then the job ends. It's one of its main benefits.

Comment: Like @kabanus said, this is exactly why coroutine cancellations and thread interruptions work by throwing an exception and not by just "killing" a background task. This is to make possible to perform a proper clean up. This is also why resource-handling mechanisms like `use()` (`try-with-resources`) or `withLock()` do a clean up in `finally` block. Java/Kotlin were always about code reliability.

Comment: @broot, Yup, good comment.

Comment: @kabanus, I'll accept your answer above and attach the conceptual changes I did to my code.

Answer (score 0):

I have accepted @kabanus answer to my problem, since it lead to my working change in my code.

The concept is (as I undestand it), that mutexes are unlocked automatically if they are in the form `mutex.withLock{ ... }` when the embracing coroutine job is cancelled.

Conceptually it looks like this:

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment(){
  //...
  val commonMutex = Mutex()
  //...
  override fun onViewCreated(view:View, savedInstanceState:Bundle?){
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    //...
    val job1:Job?=null
    val job2:Job?=null
    val job3:Job?=null
    //...
    binding.fragmentHomeMyView?.getMyAsyncView{ 
      //could be any view with async work like i.e async GoogleMaps 
      binding.apply{ //I like to let bindings embrace if they exists.
        //...
        homeViewModel.apply{ //like to let homeViewModel embrace if they exists
          //...
          liveDataSet1?.observe( //LiveData set 1 observer
            viewLifecycleOwner
          ){dataSetResult1->
            //Will check if my lengthy coroutine job 1 is still running
            //If it is -> cancel it, since the observer provides new dataset
            //Note ! If your dataset is meant to be mutable, you should do a 
            //dataset copy after the cancellation so it doesn't overrun it on next
            //observer update
            //...
            if(job1?.isActive == true){ 
              job1?.cancel()
            } 
            //...
            dataSetResult1?.apply{ //like to let the dataSet embrace if there are 
                                   //many members
              job1 = lifecycleScope.launchWhenStarted{
                //I used lifecycleScope here, you can use other coroutine "bases"
                withContext(Dispatchers.Default){
                  //Doing heavy work which doesn't imply a mutex situation
                  
                  commonMutex.withLock{ //Locking mutex section 
                    //Work on data which should be shared between two or more 
                    //coroutines 
                    withContext(Dispatchers.Main){
                      //Do screenupdates if necessary
                    } //end context main
                
                  } //end commonMutex.withLock

                }//end context default
                        
              }//end coroutine Job (lifecycleScope)
            } //end dataSetResult1 apply
          } //end dataSetResult1 observer 

          liveDataSet2?.observe( //LiveData set 2 observer
            viewLifecycleOwner
          ){dataSetResult2->
            //Will check if my lengthy coroutine job 2 is still running
            //If it is -> cancel it, since the observer provides new dataset
            //Note ! If your dataset is meant to be mutable, you should do a 
            //dataset copy after the cancellation so it doesn't overrun it on next
            //observer update
            //...
            if(job2?.isActive == true){ 
              job2?.cancel()
            } 
            //...
            dataSetResult2?.apply{ //like to let the dataSet embrace if there are 
                                   //many members
              job1 = lifecycleScope.launchWhenStarted{
                //I used lifecycleScope here, you can use other coroutine "bases"
                withContext(Dispatchers.Default){
                  //Doing heavy work which doesn't imply a mutex situation
                  
                  commonMutex.withLock{ //Locking mutex section 
                    //Work on data which should be shared between two or more 
                    //coroutines 
                    withContext(Dispatchers.Main){
                      //Do screenupdates if necessary
                    } //end context main
                
                  } //end commonMutex.withLock

                }//end context default
                        
              }//end coroutine Job (lifecycleScope)
            } //end dataSetResult2 apply
          } //end dataSetResult2 observer 

          liveDataSet3?.observe( //LiveData set 3 observer
            viewLifecycleOwner
          ){dataSetResult3->
            //Will check if my lengthy coroutine job 3 is still running
            //If it is -> cancel it, since the observer provides new dataset
            //Note ! If your dataset is meant to be mutable, you should do a 
            //dataset copy after the cancellation so it doesn't overrun it on next
            //observer update
            //...
            if(job3?.isActive == true){ 
              job3?.cancel()
            } 
            //...
            dataSetResult3?.apply{ //like to let the dataSet embrace if there are 
                                   //many members
              job3 = lifecycleScope.launchWhenStarted{
                //I used lifecycleScope here, you can use other coroutine "bases"
                withContext(Dispatchers.Default){
                  //Doing heavy work which doesn't imply a mutex situation
                  
                  commonMutex.withLock{ //Locking mutex section 
                    //Work on data which should be shared between two or more 
                    //coroutines 
                    withContext(Dispatchers.Main){
                      //Do screenupdates if necessary
                    } //end context main
                
                  } //end commonMutex.withLock

                }//end context default
                        
              }//end coroutine Job (lifecycleScope)
            } //end dataSetResult3 apply
          } //end dataSetResult3 observer 
        } //end homeViewModel.apply
      } //end binding.apply
    } //end asyncView
  } //end onViewCreated
}
```